# Method overriding - Super().<method> vs Class().<method>

Tags: python

Hi I'm practicing method overriding and trying to override fare method of parent class in the child class. Basically the idea is to override the parent class fare method
I know if I use super()., it would work but I'm curious why calling Vehicle().fare() doesn't work but super().fare() works. Thank you all

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, mileage, capacity):
        self.name = name
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.capacity = capacity
    
    def fare(self):
        return self.capacity * 100

class Bus(Vehicle):
    def fare(self):
        return int(Vehicle().fare() + Vehicle().fare()*0.1)

School_bus = Bus("School Volvo", 12, 50)
print("Total Bus fare is:", School_bus.fare())
```

Comment: When you write `Vehicle()` you are basically creating an instance of the `Vehicle` class. Surely the error you got was obvious? `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'mileage', and 'capacity'`

Comment: `Vehicle().fare()` fails for very simple and straightforward reasons. The part that takes a complex explanation is how `super().fare()` actually manages to work - `super` is really weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Vehicle()` means that you are calling the constructor for the class `Vehicle` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)). This behavior is the same anywhere in your code. This means that if you tried doing `Vehicle().fare()` you would be creating a *new* instance of the `Vehicle` class and calling the `fare()` method on that new instance. This new instance has no relationship to your `Bus` class.

This would also result in an error because you did not provide the 3 required arguments (`name`, `mileage`, `capacity`) to the `Vehicle` constructor.

`super()` is a special function that allows for a child class to call a method or constructor using the implementation in the parent class. This can be useful when you are trying to use method overloading because it removes ambiguity. It clarifies that you are trying to call a method from the parent, and not the child.

In this case, `super()` is being used to reference the implementation of `fare()` in the `Vehicle` class.

If you were creating a new method in the `Bus` class and were to call `self.fare()` this would call the implementation in `Bus`, but if you were to call `super().fare()` it would call the implementation in `Vehicle`.

Also, ignore the mean comments. Object Oriented Programming can be very tricky to learn!